# Using Multiple Spinners, But Only One Spinner Has All The Data

Tags: android

I have two spinners and two arrays.  However, one spinner receives both arrays while the other receives no values from either of the two arrays.  Note: I do not want to use radio buttons as the data is shortened for review.

```
final ArrayList<String> serialnums = new ArrayList<String>();
serialnums.add("576798");
serialnums.add("495874");
serialnums.add("345667");
serialnums.add("956345");

final ArrayList<String> carrys = new ArrayList<String>();
serialnums.add("R");
serialnums.add("L");
serialnums.add("F");
serialnums.add("B");

s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSerial);
spinnerCarry = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCarry);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, serialnums );
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCarrys = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, carrys );

s1.setAdapter(adapter);
spinnerCarry.setAdapter(adapterCarrys);
```

Note 2: Spinner `s1` gets all the data

Comment: You should add the data R,L,F,B to carry(Array) else carry(Array) would remain empty.

Answer (score 2):

One spinner has all the data because you are assigning all the data to it.  Change this:

```
final ArrayList<String> carrys = new ArrayList<String>();
serialnums.add("R");
serialnums.add("L");
serialnums.add("F");
serialnums.add("B");
```

to this:

```
final ArrayList<String> carrys = new ArrayList<String>();
carrys.add("R");
carrys.add("L");
carrys.add("F");
carrys.add("B");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding   "R"   "L"   "F"   "B"   to  `serialnums` add it to `carrys`